# Java - Use field as a variable type

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to do something similar to this:

```
public class Foo {
    public Class<?> type;
    public void FooMethod() {
        type NewClass = new type();
    }
}
```

I know this can be done with generics, but I need to make an array of the Foo type and generics don't let me to do that. Is there any other way?

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "I know this can be done with generics"? Generics will not let you invoke `new T()` because compiler can't know what type `T` will represent at runtime so it can't know if no-argument constructor will even be accessible.  Your question is not clear. I was thinking about suggesting reflection, but after it looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Nope, you cannot instantiate a generic type (e.g. `new T();`) or create an array with a generic type (e.g. `new T[size];`). You *can* create an `Object` array though and explicitly cast each element when you retrieve them from the array, e.g. `T elem = (T) array[i];`. That should cover most of the use cases for wanting generic arrays.

Comment: If you want to create an object where the object type is given by a `Class`, look at [`getConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) and [`newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-).

Comment: I agree with Pshemo--it might be helpful if we saw what you were trying to do.  Even if you post code that you would like to write, but can't because it involves an array of a generic type, that might still give us a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish.